# Error when ignoring accents in full text search using Ecto and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this search function in my controller:

```
def search(query, search_term) do
    (from u in query,
    where: fragment("(to_tsvector('portuguese', unaccent(?)) @@ plainto_tsquery(?))", u.name, ^search_term),
    order_by: fragment("ts_rank((to_tsvector('portuguese', unaccent(?)), plainto_tsquery(?))) DESC", u.name, ^search_term))
  end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR (undefined_function): function unaccent(character varying) does not exist
```

I've also added the `unaccented` extension to PostgreSQL with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

How to make this work?

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing `)` in the 2nd `fragment`, probably before `DESC`.

Comment: If that does fix it, please accept the "simple typographical error" close vote.

Comment: You're right but that was not my main issue (it was a mistake when copying code to here). I'm going to edit my error. Anyway, I think I got a clue for another step after reading some more stuff - I need to install a PostgresQL extension.

Comment: You're probably looking for `create extension unaccent` in a migration for the new error.

Comment: Ahah. I just edited my question. But I added it directly in my psql terminal. Do I need to make it inside a migration? How?

Comment: Search for "CREATE EXTENSION" on this page: https://github.com/bryanjos/geo That's how I would do it (just change the name of the extension).